# What happens if you use Pathfinder's hook on an enemy while on a zipline?

Tags: apex-legends

Do you pull him to the zipline? Do you get let go of the zipline and fly to the enemy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you hook an enemy while you are riding a zipline, you will immediately let go of the zipline. You will be pulled towards the enemy, at the same speed as they are pulled towards you. You will both end up between your two original positions, unless one of you is stuck behind something.

Comment: So just like if you pulled them while jumping?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be just like that.